# Can not pass data when adding navigation controller to view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have a TabBarController with three tabs. The views for all tabs were embedded in their own navigation controller, except one, the Map view. 
To navigate from one of the other views to the Map view and pass data I used:

```
- (IBAction)mapButton:(id)sender {
    MapViewController *destView = (MapViewController *)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([destView isKindOfClass:[MapViewController class]])
    {
        MapViewController *destinationViewController = (MapViewController *)destView;
        destinationViewController.selectedTruck = _truck;
    }
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
}
```

And it was working. Now I need to embed the Map view in a navigation controller as well, to add a detail view, but when I do no data is passed, it only goes to the Map view.

Can anyone see what am I missing?

Comment: destView is nil maybe ? it will give u a true for isKindOfClass but that does not mean it is not nil ?

Comment: i can't understand your problem .

Comment: can you  upload image of storyboard ?

Answer (score 1):

`[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]` is no longer an instance of `MapViewController`. It is a `UINavigationController` with a `MapViewController` as its root view controller.

You could access the `MapViewController` via the `UINavigationController` like so but all these type casting assumptions are messy -

```
- (IBAction)mapButton:(id)sender {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers firstObject];
    if ([navigationController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        MapViewController *rootViewController = (MapViewController *)[navigationController.viewControllers firstObject];
        if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[MapViewController class]])
        {
            MapViewController *destinationViewController = (MapViewController *)rootViewController;
            destinationViewController.selectedTruck = _truck;
        }
    }
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
}
```

Instead, a better design would be to keep a reference to the `MapViewController` (as a property) when you set up the tab bar. That way you would simply call `self.destinationViewController.selectedTruck = _truck;` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I would use something like this? UINavigationController *destViewNVC = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapNavVC"]; but then what? I am sorry, I am a bit new at this.